# Where are Glance logs? How to find benchmark problem with Glances?

Tags: command-line

```
Sudo apt-get install glances
```

In teminal to run

```
glances
```

What it shows me is sometimes some critical logs. WHere to find whats the problem? Where are thouse logs?

```
    WARNING|CRITICAL logs (lasts 10 entries)
~ 2016-03-23 19:13:46 > ___________________ LOAD 5-min (1.1/1.2/1.2) - Top process: glances
  2016-03-23 19:13:46 > 2016-03-23 19:13:49 CPU user (91.9/91.9/91.9)
  2016-03-23 19:13:24 > 2016-03-23 19:13:27 CPU IOwait (73.3/73.3/73.3)
  2016-03-23 19:13:17 > 2016-03-23 19:13:20 CPU IOwait (91.3/91.3/91.3)
  2016-03-23 19:11:13 > 2016-03-23 19:11:19 CPU IOwait (71.8/81.2/90.6)
  2016-03-23 19:09:48 > 2016-03-23 19:09:54 CPU user (72.7/76.6/80.6)
  2016-03-23 19:09:38 > 2016-03-23 19:09:44 CPU user (86.6/89.5/92.4)
  2016-03-23 19:09:32 > 2016-03-23 19:09:35 CPU user (86.4/86.4/86.4)
  2016-03-23 19:09:28 > 2016-03-23 19:09:32 CPU IOwait (62.5/62.5/62.5)
  2016-03-23 19:09:17 > 2016-03-23 19:09:25 CPU user (71.4/71.4/71.4)
```

Comment: did you find an answer about that? Thanks